# Why does this cause "Mismatched anonymous define()" in requireJS?

Tags: javascript, browser, requirejs, amd, classiejs

I'm using a module called classie.js, whose codes can be viewed below:

```
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

//transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  //browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

And I wrote this in HTML:

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
```

Then the browser complains:

```
[Error] Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: [object Object]
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
    defaultOnError (require.js, line 141)
    onError (require.js, line 545)
    intakeDefines (require.js, line 1229)
    (anonymous function) (require.js, line 1416)
```

What seems weird to me is the last lines in classie.js:

```
//transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  //browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}
```

It looks like `classie.js` tries its best to keep compatible with `AMD` because it test whether `define` is a function and has `amd` attribute before using it. But unfortunately this caused an error in the browser. Shouldn't `requirejs` the most famous library that implements AMD? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, classie is designed to be loaded with an AMD loader. So when you load it, it detect that an AMD loader is present and calls `define`.

The problem is that you are trying to load it with a `script` element. **AMD modules must be loaded through their loader**, not directly through `script`. This is why you are getting the error message you are getting.

Answer (score -2):

I just commented the AMD check and called the regular way

```
/*
// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}
*/
window.classie = classie;
```